# Best practice for use constants in scala annotations

Tags: java, scala, constants

I use tapestry 5 as my choice of web framework. Tapestry allows me to define symbols in the configure class and inject symbols into other components.

for example,

```
public interface SymbolConstants {
  static String DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_KEY = "default.timeout"; 
}

public class AppModule {
   void contributeApplicationDefault(Configuration conf) {
       conf.add(SymbolConstants.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_KEY, "10");
   }
}

public class MyComponent {
  @Symbol(SymbolConstants.DEFAULT_VALUE_KEY)
  private long timeout;
}
```

The ability to define static constants and use them as annotation values gives me compile time check.

I am wondering how to define constants and use them as values of scala annotations. If not, what is the best practice to define/limit the value that we can assign to annotations in scala.

Answer (score 23):

The 'final' keyword is required to make the compiler emit it as you would do it in Java. E.g.,

```
object Foo
{
   final val MY_SYMBOLIC_CONSTANT="whatever"
}
```

It seems that, otherwise, you only get an accessor method under the hood which is not statically calculable.

Comment: Works for me in Scala 2.10.3!

Comment: This works fine in Scala 2.10.x and Scala 2.11.x - just make sure you don't add type annotations. If you do, it seems the scala compiler decides to compile your constant to a method instead of a static final variable.

Comment: See @extempore's answer here for more background/examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19938803/scala-constant-expressions-and-computed-string-literals

Comment: Works fine for me in scala 2.12.3

Comment: Works in 2.12.2

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem possible w/ scala versions 2.8.1.final, 2.8.2.final, or 2.9.1.final (the result was the same with all):

```
object Constant { val UNCHECKED = "unchecked" }

class Test {                                       
    @SuppressWarnings(Array(Constant.UNCHECKED))   
    def test: Unit = println("testing.. 1, 2... 3")
}
```

.

```
<console>:7: error: annotation argument needs to be a constant; found: Constant.UNCHECKED
           @SuppressWarnings(Array(Constant.UNCHECKED))
```

Comment: It doesn't work because SuppressWarnings wants an array. If you use another annotations. it works. Try with @SerialVersionUID. http://www.scala-lang.org/node/106