# Scala constant expressions and computed string literals

Tags: scala

I'm running into some trickiness with Java annotations and the stipulation that their arguments must be "constants". 6.24 of the Scala 2.8 Language Specification states that "constant expressions" are any of the following (emphasis mine):

- A literal of a value class, such as an integer
- *A string literal*
- A class constructed with Predef.classOf (§12.5)
- An element of an enumeration from the underlying platform
- A literal array, of the form Array(c1, ..., cn), where all of the ci’s are themselves
  constant expressions
- An identiﬁer deﬁned by a constant value deﬁnition (§4.1).

Now, a "string literal" seems to be defined in such a way that it's really just one " " or """ """ delimited block of characters, which is pretty clear-cut. My question, then, is why given

```
object MyObject {
  final val MY_CONSTANT1="foo"
  final val MY_CONSTANT2="bar" + "baz"
  final val MY_CONSTANT3="qux" + "quux" + "frobozz"
}

// ...

@MyAnnotation( ??? )
def Foo(): Unit {
...
```

`@MyAnnotation` compiles and scaladocs with MY_CONSTANT1 and MY_CONSTANT2, but not MY_CONSTANT3 (I get "annotation argument needs to be a constant"). Why does MY_CONSTANT2 work at all? Is there some unspecified at-most-two-string-literals-can-combine-to-become-a-larger-one rule at work, or am I insane?

*edit* I'm using Scala 2.10, which seems to have fixed some annotation-related compiler errors from earlier Scala versions.

Comment: Please close the question - it's working with scala 2.10+

Comment: If it were "working" (what does that mean in this context?), I wouldn't have encountered the behavior that led me to ask the question, so no, I will not close the question.

Comment: Can you give some more detail on how to reproduce this?  This works for me in 2.10.2:

object MyObject {
   final val MY_CONSTANT1="foo"
   final val MY_CONSTANT2="bar" + "baz"
   final val MY_CONSTANT3="qux" + "quux" + "frobozz"
}

case class NoopAnnotation(val param: String) extends scala.annotation.StaticAnnotation

@NoopAnnotation("ABC")
def abc1() = 1

@NoopAnnotation(MyObject.MY_CONSTANT1)
def abc2() = 1

@NoopAnnotation(MyObject.MY_CONSTANT2)
def abc3() = 1

@NoopAnnotation(MyObject.MY_CONSTANT3)
def abc4() = 1

Comment: I'll try to find some time - hasn't happened yet. Will post an update with that info, possibly this weekend.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You say it "compiles and scaladocs", so I'm guessing your error is when you run scaladoc, as it was for me.

With scaladoc, you get a specialized compiler that only runs to the typer phase.

One of the things it customizes in its typer is:

```
override def canAdaptConstantTypeToLiteral = false
```

Change that to true, and your trivial example will scaladoc.

The big comment at the beginning of `adapt` says this is the first thing it does, or rather, the zeroth thing it doesn't do when scaladocking.

```
*  (0) Convert expressions with constant types to literals (unless in interactive/scaladoc mode)
```

Just for fun, I'll try flipping the flag to see what breaks. (Edit: the scala docs build fine. The flag grew out of presentation compiler behavior, but it's not obvious to me how it applies for scaladoc.)

Comment: Oooh, I figured it was something like that, but was clueless about where to start hunting it down.

Comment: How does one change this setting when using SBT to generate scaladoc?

Comment: @AlessandroVermeulen I don't think there is a flag for that. I must have touched the source code, rebuilt, and in build.sbt you can specify your local scala distro. I always forget how to do that. `scalaHome := Some(file("mydistro"))`. I still don't like sbt after all these years.

Answer (score 4):

All of those strings compile the same way - they are all folded into single literals. You can see them in the bytecode.

```
0: ldc           #19                 // String foo
0: ldc           #22                 // String barbaz
0: ldc           #24                 // String quxquuxfrobozz
```

To Matt Malone, you won't see "annotation argument needs to be a constant" with StaticAnnotation because it doesn't enforce anything like that. This compiles, no warnings.

```
class MyAnnotation(val s: String) extends scala.annotation.StaticAnnotation
object MyObject {
  def inconstant(): String = scala.util.Random.nextString(10)
  @MyAnnotation(s = inconstant) def f = null
}
```

The way to induce "annotation argument needs to be a constant" is to first extend ClassfileAnnotation, and then to do something which prevents the val from having a constant type. Something like this. The type ascription causes MY_CONSTANT1 to have type String instead of constant type String("foo"). You can't directly express the constant type in scala but that's how it is represented internally.

```
class MyAnnotation(val s: String) extends scala.annotation.ClassfileAnnotation
object MyObject {
  final val MY_CONSTANT1: String = "foo" 
  final val MY_CONSTANT2 = "bar" + "baz"
  final val MY_CONSTANT3 = "qux" + "quux" + "frobozz"
}
object Bippy {
  @MyAnnotation(s = MyObject.MY_CONSTANT1) def f1 = null
  @MyAnnotation(s = MyObject.MY_CONSTANT2) def f2 = null
  @MyAnnotation(s = MyObject.MY_CONSTANT3) def f3 = null
}

/***
a.scala:8: error: annotation argument needs to be a constant; found: MyObject.MY_CONSTANT1
  @MyAnnotation(s = MyObject.MY_CONSTANT1) def f1 = null
                             ^
one warning found
one error found
***/
```

Comment: If My_CONSTANTX is an Array, I couldn't even get it to work using a `final val` with no type annotation: however I was able to get it to work by passing in the expression directly ... : `@MyAnnotation(s = Array("someString"))`

Comment: Slight improvement to my above comment: `final val someString = "asdf1234"` then do `@MyAnnotation(s = Array(someString))`