# Scala behaviour when assigning literals or variables to Char

Tags: scala, char, int, variable-assignment

In Scala, if I have a variable declaration, e.g.

```
var x: Char = 'a'
```

If I then try and update this character by adding 1, e.g.

```
x = x + 1
```

I get a compilation error: Type mismatch, found Int required Char. However, I can do this without a compilation error:

```
x = 'a' + 1
```

I'm guessing this has something to do with literal values vs objects, however, I'm trying to get my head around the exact behaviour. You can clearly assign a literal integer to a Char, e.g. 97, and you can also assign the result of 97-32. However if I say 97-32+5 then I get a type mismatch error. At what point does the compiler differentiate between an expression that results in a literal vs one that result in an object?

Answer (score 1):

Assignment is the key here.
Look at the following REPL session:

```
alex@POSITRON ~ $ scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.6 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_131).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> val x:Char = 'a'
x: Char = a

scala> x + 1
res0: Int = 98

scala> var y:Char = 'a'
y: Char = a

scala> y + 1
res1: Int = 98

scala> y = y + 1
<console>:8: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int
 required: Char
       y = y + 1
             ^

scala>
```

So as you can see unless you try to reassign the variable values everything goes fine. When you write `'a'+1` or `x + 1` it gets converted to `Int`.
So when you finally try to `x = x + 1` reassign then you are trying to assign `Int` value to the `Char` variable. This explain why compilation error occurs.

In the `Char` companion object there is `implicit def char2int(x: Char): Int` method.
I think in `var x:Char = 'a' + 1` the first thing which happens is invocation of this method to convert 'a' to 97. Then 97 is added 1, both as `Int`s. Then the variable `x` gets instantiated in the same way as in `val y:Char = 98`. This I think explains how variable initialization works.

Comment: This doesn't answer why `var x: Char = a + 1` works, but `x = x + 1` doesn't. On first assignment, `a + 1` gets implicitly converted to a `Char`, but on reassignment it doesn't. Why?

Comment: I've edited my answer. If this works differently from what I think please vote for my answer deletion because then it means I do not understand the underlying stuff.

Comment: Also let's differentiate between "first assignment" and "initialization" because I think this is important. Variable initialization is not different from value initialization. I mean `val x:Char =  'a' + 1` is the same as `var x:Char = 'a' + 1` for this problem.

Comment: I've thought more about this - could it be as simple as the fact that you can assign integer literal values to Char variables but you cannot assign an Integer object/variable? In this sense does 'a' + 1 get evaluated as an integer literal, essentially just the same as assigning 98, whereas x + 1 gets evaluated as an integer object?

Comment: That's actually the same thing which I've tried to explain in the last paragraph of my answer. I think implicit conversion defined in `Char` companion object is used. Need to check the other answer which I see appeared now.

Answer (score 1):

There's a special rule for typing literals [in the spec](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/01-lexical-syntax.html#literals).

> However, if the expected type pt of a literal in an expression is
>   either Byte, Short, or Char and the integer number fits in the numeric
>   range defined by the type, then the number is converted to type pt and
>   the literal's type is pt.

That lets you write:

```
scala> 97 : Char
res0: Char = a

scala> 97 + 1 : Char
res1: Char = b
```

Sneakily, they mean constant expressions here. But the [definition](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/06-expressions.html#constant-expressions) of constant expression is platform-specific, so technically `res1` could also fail to compile, if it were not constant-folded.

A related question about [constant folding in scaladoc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19938803/1296806) shows the weird loss of type checking under scaladoc:

```
$ ~/scala-2.12.3/bin/scaladoc -d /tmp folded.scala
folded.scala:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int
 required: Char
    x = 'a' - 32 + 5
                 ^
model contains 4 documentable templates
one error found
```

Comment: If my interpretation of that paragraph from the spec is correct then 'a'+1 must result in an integer literal (of 98), which then can legitimately get assigned to a variable of type Char, as it's within the numeric range defined by that type? Whereas x + 1 must not result in a literal, so this rule doesn't apply. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, for sure `x + 1` is not a constant expression or literal, `x` is a runtime value. It's not clear to me that `x + y + z` is required to be a constant-folded literal (if the values are constants). Is the scaladoc behavior a bug or an implementation artifact? In scalac, you get the constant folding. Since nobody writes doc anymore, scaladoc is not a problem.